# What'a the difference between "wouldn't" vs "didn't" in the past

Tags: meaning, difference

1. The shop wouldn't give me a refund even though my mobile is obviously broken.
2. My parents wouldn’t lend me any money so couldn't go out.

I watched a video and found these sentences. What would it mean if I used "did" here? What's the difference?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show that you've looked up the words "would" and "did" (or rather, their present tense "will" and "do"), what you found, and what questions remain.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same meaning, but "wouldn't" is stronger than "didn't". "wouldn't" denotes a lack of permission or willingness on the part of the subject, "didn't" is quite similar, but with less emphasis. So wouldn't here would say how the shop was not willing to give you your refund, and your parents were not willing to lend you money.

You can read more [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80935/would-not-vs-did-not)