# When to use "would not" and "did not"?

Tags: sentence-construction

In the movie Angry Bird, Angry Bird says "He wouldn't even try this".

Does this mean same as "He didn't even try this"?

Context in movie:

> "It was a quality cake.
> Look, I worked very hard
> to get it there, on time.
> And he wouldn't even try it."

Comment: It means _he refused even to try it_.

Comment: [would](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would) sense 3: "used in auxiliary function to express consent or choice"

Answer (score 0):

They have the same meaning, but "wouldn't" is stronger than "didn't". "wouldn't" denotes a lack of permission or willingness on the part of the subject.

You can read more [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80935/would-not-vs-did-not)